# How setup global configuration of `httpclient` gem for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, warnings, httpclient

Every time when some gem from my application use `httpclient-2.1.0` (I don't have this gem in rails Gemfile) - it writes many warnings to log file:

```
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
opt/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_config.rb:333:in `default_verify_callback' : at depth 2 - 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain (StandardWarning)
```

Application works without errors, and I don't know what is a reason of these warning. And how I can disable it..

May I somehow globally set HttpClient configuration 'use_ssl' to false?
Please help.